# Install memcache php ext on php 5.6

Tags: php, memcache, php-memcached

I have php 5.6.6 installed on Amazon Linux. I want to install memcache extension (not memcached server, we use Elasticache). I try

```
# yum install php-pecl-memcache.x86_64
```

And get the following error:

```
Error: php56-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.29-1.7.amzn1.x86_64
```

So, is there any way to install memcache for my php 5.6 extension? If not, what should I do? Downgrade to php 5.3? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted AWS support and they helped me. The problem was connected with yum configuration. They adviced me to clone my Beanstalk environment and install memcache extension there. It helped.